# Canvas не отображается в игре, но в сцене отображается. Что делать?

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image]
Вот изображение. Есть у кого идеи в чем может быть проблема. В юнити работают не так давно, поэтому если решение ну очень уж простое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно проблема со слоем, ты его поставил за сценой(в 2д играх на юнити такое часто случается). Еще проблема может быть в том, что Canvas'у нужно задать начальные свойства и параметры(по умолчанию он будет бесцветный)